# Spring throwing 403 Forbidden on web service to upload image

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I have a controller to upload a user's avatar that has been working for quite a while. Until recently, after I made a change to my spring security configuration. The change was to have unauthorized calls to API's return 403 forbidden and unauthorized calls to anything else redirect to login. Since making this change the app throws a 403 every time a call is made to upload an avatar. Every other API works as intended.

Here are the snippets I believe are relevant to the issue at hand:

**Controller:**

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/api/users")
public class UsersController {


    @RequestMapping(value = "/upload_avatar", params = { "filename" }, method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public @ResponseBody ResponseStatusDTO handleFileUpload(
            @RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file,
            @RequestParam(value = "filename") String filename) {
        if (!file.isEmpty()) {
            try {
                String newFilename = userUtil.uploadAvatar(file, filename);
                return new ResponseStatusDTO(1, newFilename);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return new ResponseStatusDTO(1, "Failed to upload " + filename
                        + "!");
            }
        } else {
            return new ResponseStatusDTO(1, "Failed to upload " + filename
                    + " because the file was empty.");
        }
    }
}
```

**Ajax Call Performing Request:**

```
uploadAvatar : function(){
    var file = this.getSelectedFile();
    var data = new FormData();
    data.append('file', file);
    var name = file.name;

    $.ajax({
        url: './api/users/upload_avatar?filename='+ name,
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false,
        type: 'POST',
        success: _.bind(function(data){
            this.avatar = data.message;
        }, this),
        error: _.bind(function(data){
            //TODO
        }, this)
    });
}
```

**Latest Spring Security Configuration:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private CommonAuthenticationProvider authProvider;

    @Autowired
    AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;

    @Autowired
    AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

    @Autowired
    public void globalUserDetails(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth)
            throws Exception {
        auth.authenticationProvider(authProvider);
    }

    @Configuration
    @Order(1)
    public static class ApiLoginWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends
            WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

        @Autowired
        private Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint;

        @Bean
        public Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
            return new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint();
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                .and()
                    .httpBasic()
                    .authenticationEntryPoint(forbiddenEntryPoint);

            // @formatter:on
        }
    }

    @Configuration
    public static class FormLoginWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends
            WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        @Autowired
        AuthFailureHandler authFailureHandler;

        @Autowired
        AuthSuccessHandler authSuccessHandler;

        @Autowired
        private LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint loginEntryPoint;

        @Bean
        public LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint loginEntryPoint() {
            return new LoginUrlAuthenticationEntryPoint("/login");
        }

        @Override
        public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
            web.ignoring().antMatchers("/css/**", "/js/**", "/webjars/**",
                    "/login/**", "/session/**", "/public/**");
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http.authorizeRequests()
                        .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
                    .and()
                        .formLogin()
                        .loginPage("/login")
                        .loginProcessingUrl("/j_spring_security_check")
                        .usernameParameter("username")
                        .passwordParameter("password")
                        .failureHandler(authFailureHandler)
                        .successHandler(authSuccessHandler)
                        .permitAll()
                    .and()
                        .logout()
                        .logoutUrl("/j_spring_security_logout")
                        .logoutSuccessUrl("/login")
                        .invalidateHttpSession(true)
//                      .deleteCookies(cookieNamesToClear)
                    .and()
                        .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(loginEntryPoint)
                    .and()
                        .csrf().disable();
            // @formatter:on
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally found the issue after several hours. In the new api security configuration I didn't disable csrf and wasn't sending a token. Once I disabled csrf it worked as expected.

```
@Configuration
@Order(1)
public static class ApiLoginWebSecurityConfigurationAdapter extends
        WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint;

    @Bean
    public Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint forbiddenEntryPoint() {
        return new Http403ForbiddenEntryPoint();
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.antMatcher("/api/**")
                .authorizeRequests()
                .anyRequest().fullyAuthenticated()
            .and()
                .httpBasic()
                .authenticationEntryPoint(forbiddenEntryPoint)
            .and()
                .csrf().disable();
        // @formatter:on
    }
}
```